# Search For keys Matching values in a dictionary of list in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have  a dictionary of lists.

```
var dicAclWithCommonDsEffectivity = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
var list1 = new List<int>(){1,2,3};
var list2 = new List<int>(){2,4,6};
var list3 = new List<int>(){3,7,6};
var list4 = new List<int>(){8,7,6};

dicAclWithCommonDsEffectivity.Add("ab",list1);
dicAclWithCommonDsEffectivity.Add("bc",list2);
dicAclWithCommonDsEffectivity.Add("cd",list3);
dicAclWithCommonDsEffectivity.Add("de",list4);
```

I want to get the keys in dictionary for which atleast one matching value with the current key list.
for key "ab"(first list). I should get: `"ab","bc" and "cd"`.Since these lists contain one of the matching element in {1,2,3}

Is there a way without looping through each item in the list of dictionary value.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Given that it's obvious where it should be, it's simplest to just edit it in this case. I've fixed the case issues too.

Comment: (That said, I agree that it's worth posting a [mcve] rather than code that doesn't compile...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a way without looping through each item in the list of dictionary value.

*Something* has to loop - dictionaries are only designed to look up by *key*, and you're not doing that other than for the first check.

You can do this fairly easily though:

```
private IEnumerable<string> GetMatchingKeys(
    Dictionary<string, List<int>> dictionary, string key)
{
    // TODO: Use TryGetValue if key might not be in dictionary
    HashSet<int> elements = new HashSet<int>(dictionary[key]);
    return dictionary.Where(pair => pair.Value.Any(x => elements.Contains(x)))
                     .Select(pair => pair.Key);
}
```

This uses the fact that `Dictionary` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` - so the `Where` clause checks a particular entry by spotting if any of the elements of its value matches any of the elements of the original value. The `Select` clause then projects the pair to just the key.

If you need to do this a lot and you're concerned about efficiency, another alternative would be to build a second dictionary from `int` to `List<string>` - basically a reverse mapping. You'd need to maintain that, but then you could easily fetch all the "original keys" mapping to each of the values corresponding to the given key, and just use `Distinct` to avoid duplicates.

Comment: Sorry if I'm wrong: `dictionary[key]` will give NullReferenceException if Specified key is not found, So its always better to check with `ContainsKey`

Comment: @un-lucky: No, it won't give a `NullReferenceException` - it will give a `KeyNotFoundException`. You shouldn't use `ContainsKey`, because then you'll be doing the lookup twice - you should use `TryGetValue`, exactly as I've written in the comment. But I wouldn't do this if the expectation is that the key *will* be in the dictionary (and anything else represents a bug elsewhere) - in that case, an exception is appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations and suggestion of `TryGetValue` this is first time Gonna try that.

Answer (score 1):

If what you mean is to *visibly* (not *logically*) remove the looping, you could use `LINQ` with proper `Where` filter to do that and `Select` the `keys` from the `Dictionary` which have any value element(s) intersect(s) with the selected `List` (`List` in the `Dictionary` with `key == "ab"`) like this:

```
string key = "ab";
List<int> selectedList = dicAclWithCommonDsEffectivity[key];
var results = dicAclWithCommonDsEffectivity
    .Where(x => x.Value.Any(y => selectedList.Contains(y)))
    .Select(x => x.Key);
```

If you want to *logically* remove the looping too, please consider Mr. Skeet's answer.

Comment: That is going to be fairly inefficient logic on the back-end, you are going to be doing a lot of internal looping with that Intersect inside the where clause. At the very least use `.Any()` instead of `.Count() > 0`

Comment: You are right, This is only meant to visibly remove the loop. The `LINQ` would still do the loop behind the scene. I will put that note.

Answer (score 1):

It's always better to check for existence of the `searchKey` in the Dictionary before accessing them. Then you can get the associated list in the dictionary for that particular key.

You can also try like this:

```
string searchKey = "ab";
if (dicAclWithCommonDsEffectivity.ContainsKey(searchKey))
{
    var ListToSearch = dicAclWithCommonDsEffectivity[searchKey];
    var resultKeys = dicAclWithCommonDsEffectivity.Where(x => 
                                                 x.Value.Any(y => ListToSearch.Contains(y)))
                                                  .Select(x => x.Key)
                                                  .ToList();
}
else
{
    // Specified key was not found
}
```

Comment: No, it's not "always better" - if the key being missing indicates a bug elsewhere, then the exception from the dictionary indexer is entirely appropriate. If you *do* want to check, I'd suggest using `TryGetValue` instead of doing the lookup twice.